# Jquery doesn't add listner to a newly added field

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my page I have an add button to add a new field into a table:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
 var rowCount = $('#scale tr').length + 1;
 var newRow = '<tr id="row' + rowCount + '"><td>IP:</td><td> 
              <input type="text" **class="ip"** id="ip' + rowCount + '" name="ip' + rowCount + '"> </input></td><td>Name:</td><td>  <input type="text" id="n' + rowCount + '" name="n' + rowCount + '"> </input></td><td id="ip' + rowCount + 'ave"></td><td id="add"></td><td></td></tr>';
 console.log(newRow);
 $("#scale  tr:last").after(newRow);
});
```

The row is added beautifully.

I also have the following function in document ready:

```
$(".ip").focusout(function(){
    alert("here");
    var id =this.id;
    console.log(id);
    if(!ipcheck(id)){
        console.log("after function");
        $("#"+id).css("color","red");   
    }
    else(pinging(id));
});
```

This code alerts me whenever I go to the first row of the table (the one which was initially existed) however for the new rows it doesn't work. My idea is to wrap all the listeners in a function and run the function whenever anything changes however as I have a lot of such a thing in my code I was wondering if there is a better/easier way to do it.

Comment: Events do not magically get attached to new elements.

Comment: As the handler is added before the new tr item created, it was not attached to the new tr. You have to add the event handler to the newly added item.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `input` have been added dynamically to the page, all the events will not be available to this element, in this case you need to apply event delegation in order to attach those events to this newly added `input` elements:

```
$("#scale  tr:last").on("focusout",".ip",function() {
     // Your code here
})
```

Comment: You have the right idea here, but you can't delegate from the dynamically-created element (the new row). You must use an element that's available on DOM.ready.

Comment: OP is using `$("#scale  tr:last").after(newRow);` so I think `$("#scale  tr:last")` is a static parent.

Comment: Could be. I'm too tired to be sure. :-)

Comment: It didn't work for me. I just created a new function and added my listeners to it. call that function whenever I add a new row to the table and it is working.

Comment: @kou Is `#scale  tr:last` also added dynamically?

Comment: K so I ended up creating a new function and adding all the listeners to it. Every time I create a new element I call the function. This worked